# Do children inherit their parents' powers in the X-Men universe?

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers, mutant

In the X-men universe, when two mutants have a child, does the child inherit their parents' powers? If this is the case, does the child inherit only one parent's power or both, or do they develop their own separate power?

Comment: In X2, at Icemans house, Pyro states that the X-Gene is passed down by males, which confirms in the X-men universe at least, the mutant gene is hereditary but doesn't always develop into powers.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikia:

> Mutants may be born to human or mutant parents, though the odds of a mutant birth are much better for the latter. Likewise, it is rare but possible for mutant parents to have human children, termed "baseline" by characters within the Marvel Universe. Some baseline humans are genetically predisposed towards having mutant descendants such as the Guthrie family (see Cannonball, Husk, and Icarus). Mutant children born to mutant parent(s) will not necessarily have the same power(s) as their parent(s), nor will they necessarily have the same power(s) as any mutant siblings they may have; however, examples of children with the same power(s) as their parents and/or siblings are not uncommon.

Comment: FYI - probably the most well-known example of a baseline being born to two mutant parents is Graydon Creed.